# Confirm box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i new in jquery. basically what i want to do is, when user click `#modquote` it will check the textarea whether it's empty or not. If not, it will popup confirm box. if user click OK, it will proceed to the next step (line 9 and below), if CANCEL nothing will happen. My problem is when confirmation box appear, whether user click OK/CANCEL nothing happen. I just wonder, whether I can use confirm box in jquery or not, or i miss same code somewhere? Thanks you for helping..

```
    $( '#modquote')
  .click(function() {
    var msgrep = $('textarea#modrepmsg').val();
    if (msgrep != '')
    {
        confirm("test?");
        return true;
    }
    var comment = $('#repmsg').val();
    var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
    var quote = '>' + comment.replace(regex, "\n>") + '\n';
    //$("textarea#modrepmsg").html(comment.replace(regex, "\n "));
    //var quote = ">" + comment + "\n";
    //alert (quote);
    //var count = comment.length;
    $('textarea#modrepmsg').html(quote);
});
```

Comment: You're not testing the confirm result, and just returning anyway.

Comment: @MelanciaUK i thought confirm will automatic detect if user click OK, then it will return true, if click CANCEL then it will return false.

Comment: It actually does that, but you're not capturing the result or testing it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine confirm dialog with testing textArea is not empty, like

```
 $( '#modquote')
  .click(function() {
    var msgrep = $('textarea#modrepmsg').val();
    if (msgrep != '' && confirm("test?"))
    {
        var comment = $('#repmsg').val();
        var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
        var quote = '>' + comment.replace(regex, "\n>") + '\n';
        //$("textarea#modrepmsg").html(comment.replace(regex, "\n "));
        //var quote = ">" + comment + "\n";
        //alert (quote);
        //var count = comment.length;
        $('textarea#modrepmsg').html(quote);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple and yes it is possible.There is a small hack in here.Just use a setTimeout .If the user clicks the leave button..the tab will close and if user doesnt..then an alert box will pop up.put your code instead of alert box

```
var timeout;
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (){
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('execute any function instead of me!!!!'); //all your validation stuff goes here
    }, 1000);
    return "exitinggggggggggggggggggggg";
});
```

[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcCeg/7/)